# Integrating Jmeter With Selenium error is showing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

when I Integrating Jmeter With Selenium and run it the error is showing.
anyone please help me .

Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2022-03-06 14:01:19 IST
Load time:0
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:1006
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:1006
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:500
Response message:In file: inline evaluation of: `WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart() WDS.browser.get('https://www.facebook.com') WDS.s . . . '' Encountered "WDS" at line 2, column 1. in inline evaluation of:` WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart() WDS.browser.get('https://www.facebook.com') WDS.s . . . '' at line number 2

SampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/plain
DataEncoding: UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to install **Selenium/WebDriver Support** package using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/), this way you will get the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)
2. Add the configuration element for your browser and provide binary and/or driver details there
3. Add WebDriver Sampler to your test plan and put your code there

Your error means that you're trying to run your code using [Beanshell interpreter](http://www.beanshell.org/) and you're using incorrect syntax, i.e.

- Strings should be surrounded by double quotation marks
- There should be semicolons at the end of every statement

Something like:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.browser.get("https://www.facebook.com");
```

Otherwise check the page where you did get the code and pay attention to the language of the WebDriver Sampler, the default is `javascript`, the recommended is `groovy`

[image]